# split option text and show them as clickable buttons for new inputfield - jQuery

Tags: jquery, split, each

i got this selectbox

```
<select id="box" name="box">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">aa1, aa2, aa3, aa4, aa5</option>
    <option value="2">bb2, bb4, bb6, bb8</option>
    <option value="3">cc1, cc5, cc6, cc8, cc9</option>
    <option value="4">dda, ddd, ddg, ddk, ddz</option>
</select>
```

when i choose an option i display the output in a span with the name output

```
<span class="output"></span>
```

with this jQuery code

```
// This selector is called every time a select box is changed
$("#box").change(function(){
    // varible to hold string
    var str = "";
    $("#box option:selected").each(function(){
        // when the select box is changed, we add the value text to the varible
        str = $(this).text();
    });
    // then display it in the following class
    $(".output").text(str);
}).change();
```

Now i want to split the names from each selected option and create a button for the output class

you can see a demo on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LE3cM/)** (Choose a Category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// This selector is called every time a select box is changed
$("#box").change(function(){

    var text = $('option:selected', this).text();

    var opts = $('.output').empty();

    // then display it in the following class
    $.each(text.split(/,/), function(idx, value){
        value = $.trim(value);
        if(value){
            $('<a />', {
                href: '#',
                class: 'button orange',
                text: value
            }).appendTo('.output')
        }
    });
    $('#output').val('');
}).change();

// DEMO TAGS - CLICK
$('.output').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $('#output').val($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yCYac/)

Comment: hi Arun.. the click function for the buttons doesn't work anymore

Comment: @bernte it is because since the buttons are added dynamically, you need to use event delegation based event handlers

Comment: works perfect!! :D but still one problem i didn't considered. when i select an option and click the button and change now to another option the input doesn't clear! is it possible to add?

Comment: i'm going crazy :D still can't add a linebreak after $('<a /> to add a whitespace between the buttons :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34296/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-bernte)

Comment: @bernte use a simple css rule as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yCYac/4/

Answer (score 1):

Ok try it:

UPDATED:
http://jsfiddle.net/LE3cM/5/

This is what I changed:

```
str.split(/\s*,\s*/).forEach(function (x) {
     $(".output").append($('<a>').addClass('button orange').html(x).click(function () {
         $('#output').val($(this).html());
         return false;
      }));
});
```

Comment: ahh i saw you edited the script... but the empty button is still there when no option is selected

Comment: got still an empty button on first load :(

Comment: Shortly after I wrote that comment, I did another edit. Did you tried the latest version? I don't get an empty button anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[**working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LE3cM/10/)

**css**

```
.button.orange {
    background:#E3B822;
    border: 1px solid #C79F16;
    padding: 5px 10px !important;
    margin-left:10px; //added margin to give space between the anchor tags
}
```

**js**

```
$("#box").change(function () {
    var str = $.trim($("#box option:selected").text());
    $('span.output').empty();
    if (str != '') {
        str_s = str.split(',');
        $.each(str_s, function (i) {
            if ($.trim(str_s[i]) !== '') {
                $('span.output').append('<a href="#" class="button orange">' + $.trim(str_s[i]) + '</a>');
            }
        });
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: i got an empty button when no option is selected